# Rendering non-simplified Mapbox Vector Tile using mapbox gl js

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, mapbox-gl-js, simplification, vector-tiles

I am trying to render a mvt (Mapbox Vector Tile) containing OSM data using Mapbox GL js, but I keep getting some ugly polygons like they were simplified (like in the **Simplification** section of this [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/#how-to-use-vector-tiles-as-a-dataset)!). I don't want those polygons to be simplified. At least I would like the best resolution to be as close as possible from reality.

First, I checked if it could come from OSM data. But OSM data is good.
So I looked into the tile server and more precisely into the mvt encoder ([code](https://github.com/ElectronicChartCentre/java-vector-tile)). The extent value, which controls how detailed the coordinates are encoded in the vector tile, is 4096. 4096 is a very good value. So I don't understand why I don't get proper polygons.

I suppose that this issue comes from Mapbox GL js which might perform an additional simplification.

What extent value could I use in the encoder?
Is there a way to configure a resolution with mapbox gl js ?

I would appreciate some help !
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox GL JS does not do any additional simplification on vector tile sources. If you are seeing simplified geometries, this is most likely done during vector tile generation.

Comment: Agreed. The issue here is in the java-vector-tile library, not in mapbox-gl-js.

Answer (score 0):

I was finding the same thing. I got better results when, rather than importing the polygons as a geojson as I had been doing, I converted the file to a shape file, zipped it, and imported that into mapbox. There was then no simplification to the shape.